# Poisson distribution confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, estimation, poisson-distribution

Edit : this is the data I used for the first part of the problem :
\begin{matrix}
  Rocks   & 0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6 & 7\\
  samples & 12& 27& 28& 19& 8& 3& 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}

I did hypothesis to test if it follows poisson or binomial and concluded it could follow both.

### Part 2

Let p be the probability that a sample taken on a land contains strictly more than one rock.

A) What is the p value if we suppose the following : finding rock in samples follows a Poisson P(2) with $\lambda = 2$ ?

For this part I just do Poisson average is 2 and random is 1 : $0.594$

---

B) What is the *empirical proportion* $\hat p$ of the samples that contains $ > 1$ rock ?

For this part, I have, using the continuity correction ( +0.5) :

$P(X > 1 - 0.5 - 2) / \sqrt{2} =  p(z > 0.5 - 2) / 1.41 =  -1.0638$

$ = p(z < 1.0638)$

my answer : everything below 1.06 standard deviation left from the mean.
Am I right with my interpretation of *empirical proportion ?*

---

C) Give a 98 % confidence interval for $p$

I found an [interval using this calculator](http://statpages.org/confint.html) but I'm not sure if it's right to use 1 as my observed events value.

$[0.01, 6.64]$

also found this is the formula to use $\lambda \pm 1.96\sqrt{\lambda / n}$

but in my case it's going to be $\lambda \pm 1.96 * \sqrt{1}$ ?

---

D) **Test at $\alpha = 5%$ the hypothesis $p = 0.5$ versus $ p > 0.5$**

I don't know where to start this part.

Comment: Because this is a homework question, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: For (A) you haven't actually supplied a p-value. In (B), all you have to do is *count* and *add* the data. For (C), it's dangerous to use statistical tools you don't understand! (D) looks just like (A) but with $2$ replaced by $0.5$ and it's a one-sided instead of two-sided test.